# Getting Response "XML request isn't valid" when inserting a feature using wfs-t

Tags: wfs, wfs-t, tinyows

I am using [Tinyows](http://www.mapserver.org/tinyows/) to perform wfs transactions.

Here is my snippet of tinyows configuration file.

```xml
<layer retrievable="1"
   writable="1"
   ns_prefix="tows"
   ns_uri="http://www.vizexperts.com/"
   name="target_entity"
   title="Target Entities"/>
```

and this is my xml template that I'm posting to insert a target.

```xml
    <wfs:Transaction version="1.0.0" service="WFS"         xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <wfs:Insert>
    <tows:target_entity xmlns:tows="http://www.vizexperts.com/">
      <tows:name>smallOne</tows:name>
      <tows:description>adding target</tows:description>
      <tows:category>whatever</tows:category>
      <tows:grid_no>15</tows:grid_no>
      <tows:latitude>67.777</tows:latitude>
      <tows:longitude>66.55</tows:longitude>
      <tows:elevation>100.0</tows:elevation>
      <tows:geom>
      <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/xml" srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">66.55,67.777</gml:coordinates
          ></gml:Point></tows:geom>
      <tows:img_source>Some Image</tows:img_source>
    </tows:target_entity>
  </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

So after making the post request I'm getting the response that the xml is not valid.

Here is the exact response from server.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ows:ExceptionReport
 xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/ows'
 xmlns:ows='http://www.opengis.net/ows'
 xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
 xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/ows http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd'
 version='1.1.0' language='en'>
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode='InvalidParameterValue' locator='request'>
        <ows:ExceptionText>XML request isn't valid</ows:ExceptionText>

    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Please can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong with the xml template ?

[Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/kaSrh2EWgcECCUHikJtXLH) is the result of DescribeFeaureType.

Comment: what does describeFeature show?

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/kaSrh2EWgcECCUHikJtXLH) is the result of describeFeature.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Schema](http://paste.ofcode.org/kaSrh2EWgcECCUHikJtXLH) returned from DescribeFeature request it seems that your XML file is invalid, so the error message is correct if unhelpful. The schema specifies a sequence of attributes so the order is important.

Try reordering your attributes to match the schema, like this:

```
<wfs:Insert>
    <tows:target xmlns:tows="http://www.vizexperts.com/">
      <tows:category>whatever</tows:category>
      <tows:description>adding target</tows:description>
      <tows:elevation>100.0</tows:elevation>          
      <tows:geom>
      <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/xml" srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">66.55,67.777</gml:coordinates></gml:Point></tows:geom>
      <tows:grid_no>15</tows:grid_no>
      <tows:img_source>Some Image</tows:img_source>
      <tows:latitude>67.777</tows:latitude>
      <tows:longitude>66.55</tows:longitude>
      <tows:name>smallOne</tows:name>
    </tows:target>
  </wfs:Insert>
```

Comment: Tried reordering but still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there any message in the log file?

Comment: Nothing helpful. Getting the same error their also.

Comment: can you turn debuging on

Comment: Sorry but i'm not able to find how to do that. Can you please tell me how to do the same?